# Multiple Copy and Paste

Tags: c++, linux

To help me learn c++ (I've been going around in circles for a while), I've decided to write an app that gives me multiple slots to copy/past into. It probably already exists, but this is just for me.

I was wondering what the process would be to get the selected raw data from one application, and then send it to another with mine being the middle man. I'd activate the process using Ctrl-C-[Number 0-9] and Ctrl-V-[etc].

I'm using linux.

Thanks.

Comment: I could see you doing this in your own application - not sure how simple it would be to hook into everyone's application. But you said you are using this to learn c++? I don't know how much experience you have with the language itself, but it sounds like you might benefit from developing something a little less nitty-gritty at the moment.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep the ideas mill running.

Comment: Doing this properly involves dealing with X11 stuff that isn't very beginner-friendly.  It may not be a good choice for a practice project to learn C++ from.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this, but if I needed to implement it, I would start by looking at programs that access the X clipboard like xclip (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/). From there, start either reading the man pages for the X functions used in xclip or search for them on google. Some quick searches turned up this page which looks like it has some of the info you'd need: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/selection.html